# Strange character rendered correctly in notepad, but as a control character elsewhere

Tags: encoding

I have a .csv list of businesses. The file has some strange characters in. For example, in this field: `Stocktonon-Tees`, the first hyphen, between `Stockton` and `on` seems to be a character with the value `6` rather than a hyphen, with the value `45`. Stack overflow will probably sanatize this so you can't see it, so here is a pastebin:

```
http://pastebin.com/NuyyaQy9
```

Can anyone explain why this could be? Is it some encoding issue that I have missed? Or a corruption in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's almost certainly an encoding issue. A file just consists of binary data - it's how you *interpret* that binary data that matters. It sounds like Notepad is guessing at the originally-intended encoding, but whatever else you're using isn't.

Unfortunately you haven't said anything about what software is trying to read the file or what wrote it in the first place - but you should look at what encoding Notepad thinks it is, and work from there.

If it's *your* code that wrote the file out, and you get to decide the encoding, I'd recommend UTF-8 as a good general purpose, platform-portable encoding.

Comment: It's just a database of stuff I got somewhere. I tried various different encodings in firefox at the pastebin, but they all render badly, so I think the encoding must be an obscure one.

Comment: @Oliver: Quite possibly not - if Notepad is getting it right, it may well be Windows-1252.